# Agrupar por id, y transformar en nuevas columnas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Mi dataframe es el siguiente

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['1', '1','1', '1', '2','2', '3', '3', '3','3','3','3'], 
               'Food': ['Milk', 'Milk', 'Egg', 'Egg', 'Egg', 'Bread', 'Milk', 'Milk', 
               'Bread', 'Bread', 'Bread', 'Bread']})
```

Mi salida esperada

```
Day     Milk  Egg    Bread
 1       2     2       0
 2       0     1       1
 3       2     0       4
```

Mi intento fue

```
new_df = df.groupby('Day').Food.value_counts()
```

Pero no sé como poner la 'categoria' en nueva columna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Casi lo logras, lo que puedes hacer es agregar [`pandas.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) para separar en las columnas de cada alimento y [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) para rellenar todos los `NaN` con `0`

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['1', '1','1', '1', '2','2', '3', '3', '3','3','3','3'], 
               'Food': ['Milk', 'Milk', 'Egg', 'Egg', 'Egg', 'Bread', 'Milk', 'Milk', 
               'Bread', 'Bread', 'Bread', 'Bread']})
new_df = df.groupby('Day').Food.value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
print(new_df)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
Food  Bread  Egg  Milk
Day                   
1       0.0  2.0   2.0
2       1.0  1.0   0.0
3       4.0  0.0   2.0
```